# How to store seperate lines of a file in variables

Tags: python, file, python-2.7, tkinter, widget

I am creating a Tkinter program to read a file and print each line into a label. I think that the best way to do that is to have each line saved as a variable. How can I specify which line to read with `file.readline()` or do I need some other command? Also I know this isn't stated in my title. But how would I get the labels to update every few seconds or at the click of a button?

Comment: Are you saying into one label updating in a loop or what exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like:

```
open('path/to/file').readlines()
```

Then you have a list in which each position is a file line. Check https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html, also be carefully with the size of the file and manage the possible exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

What you might do is read the whole in a list of strings and get the line you want by indexing the list:

```
>>> f=open(myfile)
>>> l=f.readlines()
>>> #First line
>>> l[0]
'This is the first line'
>>> l[-1]#Last line
'This is the last line'
>>> f.close()
```

As for your other question, I am not that much into gui / ktinker, so maybe someone else can help you on that?